# query performance improvement suggestion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I was trying to optimize below query. its updating a temp table. i think because of subqueries its taking a lot of time to execute. is there any alternate way to write this query effectively?

```
UPDATE CA
SET CA.GP = (ISNULL(BOY.GP, 0) + ISNULL(CA.GP, 0) + ISNULL(NI.GP, 0) + ISNULL(TI.GP, 0) + ISNULL(OI.GP, 0)) - (ISNULL(NDE.GP, 0) + ISNULL(DS.GP, 0) + ISNULL(OD.GP, 0)),
    CA.B7 = (ISNULL(BOY.B7, 0) + ISNULL(CA.B7, 0) + ISNULL(NI.B7, 0) + ISNULL(TI.B7, 0) + ISNULL(OI.B7, 0)) - (ISNULL(NDE.B7, 0) + ISNULL(DS.B7, 0) + ISNULL(OD.B7, 0)),
    CA.TB = (ISNULL(BOY.TB, 0) + ISNULL(CA.TB, 0) + ISNULL(TI.TB, 0) + ISNULL(OI.TB, 0)) - (ISNULL(NDE.TB, 0) + ISNULL(DS.TB, 0) + ISNULL(OD.TB, 0)),
    CA.Other = (ISNULL(BOY.Other, 0) + ISNULL(CA.Other, 0) + ISNULL(NI.Other, 0) + ISNULL(TI.Other, 0) + ISNULL(OI.Other, 0)) - (ISNULL(NDE.Other, 0) + ISNULL(DS.Other, 0) + ISNULL(OD.Other, 0))
FROM #CADetail CA
     JOIN (SELECT GP,
                  B7,
                  TB,
                  Other,
                  TC
           FROM #CADetail
           WHERE CAAccount = N'Balance at beginning of year') BOY ON BOY.TC = CA.TC
     JOIN (SELECT GP,
                  B7,
                  TB,
                  Other,
                  TC
           FROM #CADetail
           WHERE CAAccount = N'CA Contributed') CA ON CA.TC = CA.TC
     JOIN (SELECT GP,
                  B7,
                  TB,
                  Other,
                  TC
           FROM #CADetail
           WHERE CAAccount = N'Net Income/Loss') NI ON NI.TC = CA.TC
     JOIN (SELECT GP,
                  B7,
                  TB,
                  Other,
                  TC
           FROM #CADetail
           WHERE CAAccount = N'T Exempt Income') TI ON TI.TC = CA.TC
     JOIN (SELECT GP,
                  B7,
                  TB,
                  Other,
                  TC
           FROM #CADetail
           WHERE CAAccount = N'Other Increases') OI ON OI.TC = CA.TC
     JOIN (SELECT GP,
                  B7,
                  TB,
                  Other,
                  TC
           FROM #CADetail
           WHERE CAAccount = N'Non-Deductible Expenses') NDE ON NDE.TC = CA.TC
     JOIN (SELECT GP,
                  B7,
                  TB,
                  Other,
                  TC
           FROM #CADetail
           WHERE CAAccount = N'DSs') DS ON DS.TC = CA.TC
     JOIN (SELECT GP,
                  B7,
                  TB,
                  Other,
                  TC
           FROM #CADetail
           WHERE CAAccount = N'Other Decreases') OD ON OD.TC = CA.TC
WHERE CA.CAAccount = N'Balance at end of year';
```

above update statement is taking around 15 minute to get update. is there any better way to optimize this query?

Comment: Why are you using joins to subqueries? What's wrong with something like `JOIN #CADetail BOY ON BOY.TC = CA.TC AND BOY.CAAccount = N'Balance at beginning of year'`? Looks like you don't have a `WHERE`; how many rows are you updated here?

Comment: @Larnu i just tried it and its also taking same time

Comment: I wasn't saying that'll fix it, just asking why you're doing that (as it make the code a lot harder to read). You didn't answer about the rows though; how many *are* you updating?

Comment: 650 rows need to get updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to calculate the values:

```
UPDATE CA
    SET CA.GP = TOTAL_GP,
        CA.B7 = TOTAL_B7,
        CA.TB = TOTAL_TB,
        CA.Other = TOTAL_OTHER
FROM (SELECT CA.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN CAAccount IN (N'T Exempt Income', N'Other Increases', . . .)
                      THEN GP ELSE 0
                 END) OVER (PARTITION BY TC) as total_gp,
             SUM(CASE WHEN CAAccount IN (N'T Exempt Income', N'Other Increases', . . .)
                      THEN B7 ELSE 0
                 END) OVER (PARTITION BY TC) as total_b7,
             SUM(CASE WHEN CAAccount IN (N'T Exempt Income', N'Other Increases', . . .)
                      THEN TB ELSE 0
                 END) OVER (PARTITION BY TC) as total_tb,
             SUM(CASE WHEN CAAccount IN (N'T Exempt Income', N'Other Increases', . . .)
                      THEN other ELSE 0
                 END) OVER (PARTITION BY TC) as total_other    
      FROM #CADetail CA
     ) CA
WHERE CA.CAAccount = N'Balance at end of year';
```

Note the `IN` list need to include all the types of accounts you are interested in.

Comment: thank you.but i have a substraction also. how to add it.

Comment: @vinton . . . Add another `SUM()` for the columns that need to be negated and just subtract that value.

Comment: i added like below.(first GP condition) .is it correct CASE WHEN CAAccount IN (N'T Exempt Income', N'Other Increases', . . .)
                      THEN GP 
       case when CAAccount IN (N'some condi' ) then -1*GP ELSE 0

Comment: i tried this but the result of sum fields are different from the previous result

Comment: when i tried the above solution my query performance got improved. before it was taking 15 minutes. now its taking only 8 seconds. but the sum value is not correct. any idea